# Looking fo a free type specimen book creator for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, font-utility

I'm looking for a Windows-running equivalent of [Veenix TypeBook Creator](http://www.veenix.com/FontTools.html). I want to batch print a paragraph of text (not a simple phrase or pangram but a real paragraph) for a large amount of fonts (type 1 and OTF): one font/style = one paragraph.

I've seen lots of softwares, but they have either severe limitations, or are expensive, or runs only on Macs. The amount of type manager software is really massive; any help would be appreciated to find the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it with a Shell or Batch script which makes use of LaTeX and ***[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)***?

Once you have LaTeX and Pandoc installed and have your paragraph's text in a text file called `mytext.txt`, you could do this:

```
for i in ${HOME}/myfonts/*.ttf ; do
    pandoc                                                           \
       -o testpage-$(basename "${i}").pdf                            \
       -V geometry:"margin=1.5cm, paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=12cm" \
       -V mainfont="${i}"                                            \
       --latex-engine=lualatex                                       \
          mytext.txt ;
done
```

This would give you a 1-page PDF file for each font. Then concatenate these PDFs with the help of `pdftk`:

```
 pdftk testpage-*.pdf cat output font-specimen-book.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally tried Bitstream Font Navigator, which is discontinued but could be found bundled with Corel Draw trial, and seems to be usable with no trial limit.

It does exactly what I asked for; i just hope it's not limited–I'm still interested in a real freeware that could do the trick.